# Java addition giving wrong answer

Tags: java

I am trying to add four integers ie 4+3+2+1 but i get the value 202

```
class Task3{
public static void main (String args[]){
    String x=(args[0]);
    int I = Integer.parseInt (x);   
    char c1 = x.charAt(0);
    char c2 = x.charAt(1);
    char c3 = x.charAt(2);
    char c4 = x.charAt(3);
    System.out.println("First and last digit is: " + c1 +"," + c4);
    if (c1 > c4)
        System.out.println("The first digit is larger");
    else
        System.out.println("The second digit is larger");
    int sum = c1 + c2 + c3 + c4;
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

}

Comment: Because this is the sum of their [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) values.

Comment: remember you sum the values of '4' '3' '2'  and '1' ascii and not their value (4 3 2 or 1). parse it before sum

Comment: ohhh!! you are trying to add chars to get the integer value great.

Comment: you know what `c1+c2+c3+c4` add up to?. They will give you *ascii* values of characters.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Not ASCII values; UTF-16 code units values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `char c1 = x.charAt(0);` with `Character.getNumericValue(x.charAt(0))`

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are adding numeric values of UNICODE code points, not digits represented by the corresponding characters.

In order to get a digit from a character code, call `Character.digit(c1, 10)` (ten indicates that you want a decimal digit).

```
int c1 = Character.digit(x.charAt(0), 10);
int c2 = Character.digit(x.charAt(1), 10);
int c3 = Character.digit(x.charAt(2), 10);
int c4 = Character.digit(x.charAt(3), 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
int sum = c1 + c2 + c3 + c4;
```

to

```
int sum = c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 - 4 * '0';
```

Since c1, c2, c3, c4 are all characters, so a digit say. 4 is taken as '4' that is basically the ASCII value, so to get 4 and not '4' you need to subtract '0' from each of c1, c2, c3, c4, so 4 * '0' subtracted

Comment: Cool approach, but you should explain why he has to subtract `4 * '0'` :)

Comment: @kocko, if you have to explain it, then it's a dirty hack.  I don't know about "cool" code, but where I work, we like to see every line of code explain itself.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to sum up the `char`s ASCII codes and not the digit values. You have to retrieve the corresponding digit for each character and then evaluate you addition result:

```
class Task3
{
  public static void main (String args[])
  {
    String x=(args[0]);
    int I = Integer.parseInt (x);   
    char c1 = x.charAt(0);
    char c2 = x.charAt(1);
    char c3 = x.charAt(2);
    char c4 = x.charAt(3);
    int i1 = Character.digit(c1, 10);
    int i2 = Character.digit(c2, 10);
    int i3 = Character.digit(c3, 10);
    int i4 = Character.digit(c4, 10);
    System.out.println("First and last digit is: " + i1 +"," + i4);
    if (i1 > i4)
      System.out.println("The first digit is larger");
    else
      System.out.println("The second digit is larger");
    int sum = i1 + i2 + i3 + i4;
    System.out.println(sum);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the wrong output others already explained it now one of the way to get the correct output

```
int sum =0;
while(I>0){
    int rem = I%10;
    sum+=rem;
    I = I/10;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are passing "4321" or similar to the program.

c1 will not be the number 1 but actually the Unicode number representing the character '1' which is actually 31 (in hexadecimal).  The latest addition is adding these Unicode numbers.

See http://unicode-table.com/en/ for the list of unicode numbers to characters and also  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html for more details of characters in Java.